# Is it legitimate in modern C++ to define a return variable in the function declaration?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration

I found a strange piece of C++ grammar on [CodeSignal](https://app.codesignal.com/):

```
string r, longestDigitsPrefix(string s)
{
   for(auto const c : s)
   {
      if(isdigit(c))
        r += c;
      else
        break;
   }
   return r;
}
```

The first line is defining `string r` before the function declaration. Is this valid in modern C++?

The above code compiles and passes all tests in the CodeSignal console, but it produced a compiler error when I tried to compile locally (`--std=c++14`).

Is this is valid grammar in modern C++? If so, which standard revision does it comply with?

Comment: Where did you find this and what compiler accept this? Never saw this (invalid) grammar.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - Upon closer inspection, different branches of the grammar production.

Comment: @StoryTeller Meaning that it's valid or invalid?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - Invalid. The grammar production I was looking it described `decl a; decl b;` - `a` or `b` can be function definitions (note the semicolon). But a function definition may not appear in `decl a, b;`

Comment: `string r, longestDigitsPrefix(string s);` would be valid. The code you posted is invalid.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the verification!

Comment: You should really post MCVE version of this, one you yourself used with your compiler.

Comment: Is that code snippet part of a larger code? can you add more context to that code snippet?

Answer (score 55):

Yeah, C++ grammar is weird. Basically, when it comes to *declarations* (and only declarations), we have this thing where:

```
T D1, D2, ... ,Dn;
```

means ([[dcl.dcl]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.decl-3)):

```
T D1;
T D2;
...
T Dn;
```

This will be familiar in the normal cases:

```
int a, b; // declares two ints
```

And probably in the cases you've been told to worry about:

```
int* a, b, *c; // a and c are pointers to int, b is just an int
```

But declarators can introduce other things too:

```
int *a, b[10], (*c)[10], d(int);
```

Here `a` is a pointer to int, `b` is an array of 10 `int`s, `c` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s, and `d` is a function taking an `int` returning an `int`.

---

However, this *only* applies to declarations. So this:

```
string r, longestDigitsPrefix(string s);
```

is a valid C++ declaration that declares `r` to be a `string` and `longestDigitsPrefix` to be a function taking a `string` and returning a `string`.

But this:

```
string r, longestDigitsPrefix(string s) { return s; }
```

is invalid C++. Function definitions have their own grammar and cannot appear as part of the *init-declarator-list*.

The definition of that function is also bad, since it's using a global variable to keep track of state. So even if it were valid, `longestDigitsPrefix("12c")` would return `"12"` the first time but `"1212"` the second time...

Comment: I think your answer is not complete, one could also think about the "Built-in comma operator
The comma operator expressions have the form
E1 , E2  
In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded " https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: The comma operator can be used as part of an *expression*, but the code proposed here syntactically isn’t an expression (it’s a *statement*), so I don’t think there’s a need to look at the comma operator in refuting that this is syntactically correct.

Comment: @templatetypedef It's hard to reason about grammatically incorrect statements, I was trying to cover all cases one could think of when seeing a comma in such context, but I see your point.

Comment: @templatetypedef: It's not a statement; those can only appear inside statement blocks.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I stand corrected! What would this syntax be, then? Just a pure declaration?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Yes.  Well, the legal syntax (with the two parts separated).  That's what allows it to appear at file/namespace/class body scopes, where statements aren't legal.

Answer (score 4):

By reading the ISO C++14 draft N4140 Annex A [gram], I'm pretty sure it's incorrect since I cant find a way to deduce the grammar from a translation unit from

> translation-unit -> declaration-seq -> declaration -> block-declaration | function-definition | linkage-specification | ...
>
> function-definition: attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt
>   declarator virt-specifier-seqopt function-body
>
> declarator: ptr-declarator noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
>   trailing-return-type

But your line is more the comma operator but its grammar is:

> expression: 
>   assignment-expression | expression , assignment-expression
>
> assignment-expression: conditional-expression | logical-or-expression |
>   assignment-operator | initializer-clause | throw-expression

And there is no way from `assignment-expression` to `function-definition`

Update:
Thanks to Barry, another way to try to buttom-up parse your text is by rather try to get from a `init-declarator-list` (which you can get from `block-declaration`) to a `function-definition`:

> init-declarator-list: init-declarator | init-declarator-list ,
>   init-declarator
>
> init-declarator: declarator initializeropt

And

> declarator: ptr-declarator noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
>   trailing-return-type

Would allow you a function declaration but not definition. So this odd code would be legal:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

string r, longestDigitsPrefix(string s);

string longestDigitsPrefix(string s) {
    for(auto const c : s)
    {
        if(isdigit(c))
            r += c;
        else
            break;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    longestDigitsPrefix("foo");

    return 0;
}
```

However I could be wrong, since I'm not used to use the formal grammar of C++, which is normal since it's grammar is very complex, and has some non trivial behaviour.

Answer (score -4):

To my knowledge, this is not a valid function declaration.

The prefix in functions can be used only as a way to define what type is the function's "returning" variable, not the variable itself.

You can however declare a variable outside your function (thus making it global) and modify it inside the function, as you may have probably attempted, but then you need to pass said variable as a reference in your function's arguments. You would also need to set your function as void, since it is not going to return the variable, but just modify it

Example

```
std::string foo = "Hello";

void foo_func(std::string &string)
{ //do something with the string
}

//call the function and modify the global "foo" string
foo_func(foo);
```

Comment: As the question has a `language-lawyer` tag, we expect answers with C++ standard quotes.

Answer (score -5):

If you are doing this as an optimization, then as long as there is only one variable being returned, then most compilers will have the return variable allocated on the caller's stack, rather than the callee's.

All you have to do is declare the variable in callee's context, and make sure there is either 1 return point, or all return points return the same variable.

Comment: As the question has a `language-lawyer` tag, we expect answers with C++ standard quotes.